# Como dividir propriamente duas variáveis?

Tags: python, conversão-de-tipo, float

No código abaixo eu tento dividir os valores, mas acabo recebendo uma resposta completamente errada do cálculo:

```
nota1 = input ("Digite a nota 1: ")
nota12 = input ("Digite a nota 1: ")

nota2 = input ("Digite a nota 2: ")
nota22 = input ("Digite a nota 2: ")
media1 = (float(nota1 + nota12)/2)
media2 = (float(nota2 + nota22)/2)

print(media1)
print(media2)
```

O resultado que consigo é esse:

[image: Imagem]

Como consigo com que o cálculo saia corretamente (5+10/2 = 7.5 e 7+7/2=7)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa converter já na aquisição dos dados. O que o seu código está fazendo é somar duas *strings* e depois converter para `float`. O problema é que somar *string* é uma concatenação, então quando digita 5 e 10, está pegando 510.

Simplificadamente pode fazer assim:

```
nota1 = float(input("Digite a nota 1: "))
nota12 = float(input("Digite a nota 1: "))

nota2 = float(input("Digite a nota 2: "))
nota22 = float(input("Digite a nota 2: "))
media1 = ((nota1 + nota12) / 2)
media2 = ((nota2 + nota22) / 2)

print(media1)
print(media2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/drccMr). E [também no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gbgazkby-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ConvertStringToFloat.py).

Mas note que este código não está tratando possível erros de digitação. O mais correto é capturar a exceção que pode gerar ou verificar se o que foi digitado está ok.